# Creating correct texture coordinates for a sphere in opengl

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm currently trying to render a sky dome. The sphere is created using gluSphere and inside a vertex shader I extract the spherical coordinates from each vertex. I then map both sphere coordinates theta and phi to the range [0,1], just like normal texture coordinates. Currently, the fragment shader only considers phi.

As you can see, phi doesn't seem to be mapped correctly, since the gradient appears two times, implying that phi is reset after pi revolutions.

I calculate theta and phi in the VS like this:

```
theta = acos(gl_Vertex.y/radius)/(pi);
phi = (atan(gl_Vertex.x/gl_Vertex.z)+pi)/(2*pi);
```

The color in the FS is simply:

```
gl_FragData[0].rgb = vec3(phi, phi, phi);
```

[image: problem image]

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to do. Does you want to map texture on sphere or  other-things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I was using atan(float x), instead of atan(float x, float y) which essentially is atan2.

Comment: You are giving answer by user self or you want to comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map a texture on sphere created using gluSphere then no need to generate the spherical coordinate you can map texture on it using gluQuadricTexture. You can see the sample example program [here](http://codeincodeblock.blogspot.com/2012/05/simple-method-for-texture-mapping-on.html) .